# Поиск элемента массива методом Фибоначи на с++

Tags: c++

Уже довольно долго сижу над этой задачей, но чувствую, что зашёл в тупик.

```
long int Fib(int i)

{

    int value = 0;

    if (i < 1) return 0;

    if (i == 1) return 1;

    return Fib(i - 1) + Fib(i - 2);
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");

    int N;
    cout << "Введите размер массива: " << endl;
    cin >> N;

    int* arr = new int[N];
    int key;

    cout << "Заполните массив целыми числами: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i != N; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    sort(arr, arr + N);

    cout << endl << "Введите ключ: ";

    cin >> key;

    bool flag = false;
    int l = 0;
    int r = N;
    int i=0;
    while ((l <= r) && (flag != true)) {

        if (arr[Fib(i)] == key) flag = true;
        if (arr[Fib(i)] > key) r = Fib(i);
    }

    if (flag) cout << "Индекс элемента " << key << " в массиве равен: " << Fib(i);
    else cout << "Извините, но такого элемента в массиве нет";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь я пытался сперва через функцию задать последовательное нахождение чисел фибоначи, тем не менее, поиск не удаётся — консоль прекращает работать после ввода ключа (индекса искомого элемента). Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь свежим взглядом посмотрит код и укажет мне на ошибку. Заранее спасибо.

P.S.
Для незнающих о методе поиска:

> С помощью чисел фибоначи находим индексы,значения которых будет равно
>   искомому числу.Если искомое число больше,значит ещем следующее число
>   фибоначи,если равно то возвращаем.Идем до тех пор,пока не будет
>   значение индекса массива числа фибоначи больше искомого числа.Если
>   равно,то возвращаем.Если больше,то обрезаем массив,начальный индекс
>   будет равен предыдущему индексу числа фибаначи,и последний текущему.И
>   заново ищем число по методу фибоначи по такому же принципу.

Comment: `return Fib(i - 1) + Fib(i - 2);` кто вас так писать учит...

Answer (score 0):

https://www.onlinegdb.com/
В начале массив [1 2 3]
ищем 3

```
i=0;
l=0;
r=N;
flag=false;
```

далее

```
if (arr[Fib(i)] == key) flag = true;
```

Условие ложно.

```
if (arr[Fib(i)] > key) r = Fib(i);
```

И это тоже.
В итоге цикл для данных исходных данных значит:

```
while (true);
```

Что за алгоритм реализовывался я так и не понял.

Советую посмотреть про отладчик Visual:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/quickstart-debug-with-cplusplus?view=vs-2019

Comment: Это заявление о том, что не понятен код в вопросе, а не ответ

Comment: Это мой взгляд на этот код.

Comment: Помню когда-то у меня были такие-же проблемы... Раза после 30 пришлось учится пользоваться отладчиком.

Answer (score 0):

Если в ответе "Данила Наширбанова" исправить `else` 45-я строка в методе `fibonacciSearch` следующим образом:

```
// Если искомый элемент меньше текущего, сдвигаем индекс на (F_{i-1}) элементов
    else {
        fib2 = fib1 - fib2;
        fib1 = fib1 - fib2;
        i = fib2;
        j = j - min(fib2, j-i);
    }
```

получится вполне рабочий вариант.